# Android Studio Mac Gradle not compatible with JDK

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio, gradle

When I try to build the project:

```
5:33 pm Gradle sync started

5:33 pm Gradle sync failed: Could not determine java version from '11.0.8'.
                The project uses Gradle version which is incompatible with Studio running on Java 10 or newer.
                See details at https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8431
                Possible solution:
                - Upgrade Gradle wrapper to 4.8.1 version and re-import the project
                (2 s 910 ms)

5:33 pm Android Studio is using the following JDK location when running Gradle:
                /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
                Using different JDK locations on different processes might cause Gradle to
                spawn multiple daemons, for example, by executing Gradle tasks from a terminal
                while using Android Studio.
                More info...
                Select a JDK from the File System
                Do not show this warning again
```

When I press the link to upgrade Gradle:

```
Could not determine java version from '11.0.8'.

The project uses Gradle version which is incompatible with Studio running on Java 10 or newer.
See details at https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8431
Possible solution:
 - Upgrade Gradle wrapper to 4.8.1 version and re-import the project
```

It is saying I have Java 11.0.8 when the JDK location is very clearly pointing at Java 8, and changing the Gradle version fails.

The steps I took to fix this were to make sure JDK was < 10 which it states it has to be. Since JDK = 8, this should be fulfilled.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: May I ask why you're using such an old version of Gradle that it's recommending you upgrade to Gradle 4.8.1? The latest version of Gradle is 7.1. Also, _maybe_ [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#jdk) can help?

Comment: I am not sure. I got sent a zip file full of source code for the project I have to work on. It is not even in a git repo, so I am not 100% sure what is going on here.

Comment: That URL to Google documentation is weird as it is pointing me at a "Gradle JDK" option in preferences which does not exist.

Comment: Hm. That is strange (maybe somethings changed and that documentation is out-of-date or from an old version). To be honest, I'm not that familiar with Android Studio. I just know that on IntelliJ IDEA some times the problem is that Gradle is set to use a different JDK than the project. And Android Studio is based of the IntelliJ Platform so I was guessing maybe you were encountering the same problem.